# Write each partition data in a single file in S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have use-case where we want to partition the data frame by a column value and then write each partition into single file. I did following things to do the same:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("hdfs:///tmp/PartitionKeyedDataset.csv")

df.repartition($"_c1")

df.rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3://dfdf/test1234")
```

When i do:

```
df.rdd.partitions.size
```

I get only 62 partition.But, the distinct values for the column is 10,214 (got it by running df.select("_c1").distinct.count)

I can't use:

```
df.write.partitionBy("_c1").save("s3://dfdf/test123")
```

as this creates the folder in destination with partition name. We don't want this. We want only files to be dumped.

Comment: Is it that you want just one file?

Comment: one file per partition

Answer (score 2):

I did a silly mistake of not using new variable. Hence, i saw same number of partition. Below is the updated code:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("hdfs:///tmp/PartitionKeyedDataset.csv")

df.repartition($"_c1")

df.rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3://dfdf/test1234")
```

repartition will only create 200 partitions by default as the default value for spark.sql.shuffle.partitions is 200. I have set this value to number of unique values i have for the column on which i want to partition.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "10214")
```

After this, i got 10214 partitions and write operation created 10214 files in S3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the new dataframe to a variable and use that instead. Currently in your code the `repartition` part does not actually do anything.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("hdfs:///tmp/PartitionKeyedDataset.csv")
val df2 = df.repartition($"_c1")
df2.rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3://dfdf/test1234")
```

Although it is possible to change the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` setting, that is not as flexible.